# Close radar plot in plot.states.radar function of ProjecTILs package

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am trying to use the ProjecTILs package in R and when I try to generate radarplots they aren't "closed" - the first and last points are not connected so the internal shading is off. I have attached an example below. This is despite them appearing normal in any vignette I have seen for the package.

Does anyone have any tips or corrections to the source (if that is the issue)?

[image]

I have tried to add bits of code from what I have seen online to redefine the function but I do not know enough about this and it hasn't worked.